# re-setting password on grub wont accept new passwords "passwords do not match"

Tags: 12.04

so I have x2 netbooks for my twins birthdays.  Neither came with/people can remember the passwords.

I know all the info about going into grub and I can get right up until inputting new unix (sp?) password.  I know the typed password does not come up on the screen.  No matter what I try it always comes back at me saying passwords dont match.   What the hell is going on here?????????   Am I missing something... how long does the password have to be.

I have to get these up and running for xmas eve and am panicking now.

Comment: What is your question? I'm trying to know what is your need? do you want to know how to reset your password?

Comment: I want to reset my password but it wont let me on grub - keeps coming up with passwords do not match.  I don't know what else to do...

Comment: I dont have a live cd

Comment: you have to get one to restore ur password... unless u remember your root password.. Do you?

Comment: no these are 2nd hand netbooks.  where do I get a cd from?

Comment: Ubuntu Installation CD... you can get it from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I wish I knew why it wasnt accepting the new passwords though.  Is there any rules to the password?

Comment: Sure you are not writing the correct passwords

Comment: yes I am writing the same thing on both lines.   Do they have to be any particular length or have capital letters etc?

Comment: I'm really so confused of you.. I just not understanding what are your needs please edit your question and clarify more your needs in details

Comment: I dont understand what is confusing either!   I want to reset my password but it is not happening.   They are netbooks so I cannot make a cd to reboot.  I will probably have to wipe ubuntu and put windows on I have no idea why they would make a system so reliant on one password.

Comment: Problem is not in Ubuntu... A system is not responsible for forgetting passwords... anyway you can also use USB as live USB instead of CD check this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: you can then make the steps below when u boot from usb

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD, choosing “Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer” from the boot menu.

Once the system boots, open up a new Terminal window from Applications \ Accessories and then type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command is used to tell what device name the hard drive is using, "The entry with * before"

I assume its sda1 for the rest

Now you’ll need to create a directory to mount the hard drive on. Since we’re actually booting off the live cd, the directory doesn’t really get created anywhere.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
```

The next command will mount the hard drive in the /media/sda1 folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

Now it’s time for the command that actually does the magic: chroot. This command is used to open up a shell with a different root directory than the current shell is using, and we’ll pass in the folder where we mounted the hard drive.

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

Now you should be able to use the passwd command to change your user account’s password, and it will be applied to the hard drive since we are using chroot.

```
passwd USERNAME
```

Note that you’ll have to type your username after the passwd command in order to change the right password.

Now you should be able to reboot your system and log yourself in with your new password.

Comment: sorry I dont have a cd.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The resolution is explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword.

In case the link dies, the problem seems to be a lack of write access which you need to change your password. The solution is simply to type

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Do this step immediately before the `passwd username` step. This worked for me.